# Installation of maven eclipse plugin doesn't finish

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

Hello I'm trying to install maven plugin with eclipse and I have a following problem, more in picture below :

[image]

So my question is, is this supposed to take this long or I did something wrong?

I'm using eclipse galileo , I went to the window-> install new software -> typed in

```
http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update/ website and name maven
```

Pressed next then finish, did I do something wrong, or is there another way  to get maven working with eclipse? I need it for my project . thank you

Comment: You did it the right way, something probably went wrong. There might also be a user license that you need to accept before the installation can proceed.

Comment: well I wasn't asked anything like with usual plugins I was just offered finnish button... thats it

Comment: This is not supposed to be very long (unless you are using a 56k modem). Maybe give the Maven Integration for Eclipse Dev Update Site - http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update-dev/ a try.

Comment: how can I accept your answer you posted a comment, please post an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, update site url you pasted is url for stable version builds. According [this document](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Installation+Requirements) stable version of m2eclipse works with Eclipse 3.2, 3.3 or 3.4.

To work with Galileo version (Eclipse 3.5) try update from [stable development builds site](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update-dev/). I work with this version and I'm happy with it. It has a lot more features than stable one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) instead of m2eclipse.

With maven-eclipse-plugin you just add some configuration to pom.xml, execute `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and refresh project in Eclipse and you are done.

You will lose UI to handle dependencies etc. directly from IDE (that would be provided by m2eclipse) but I have not seen much benefit from that. You can manually edit pom.xml just fine.